# Is this the right way to scrape multiple URLs simulateneously in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python, I'm creating a web scraper for scraping a torrent site. In order to obtain magnet links, I have made it scrape every torrent URL. The problem is there are ~20 links to scrape in every search. This takes a very long time to complete. So, I split the URL Scrape list into three using numpy and tried to scrape all the three lists at same time using threads. It seems to be faster but I'm not sure if this is the right way for doing this. Is this the correct way to scrape multiple urls at once?

Thanks

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import cfscrape
import threading
import os

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper()

source=scraper.get("https://1337x.to/search/big+buck+bunny/1/").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

tablebody = soup.find('tbody')

urllist=[]
filenamelist=[]
seederlist=[]
leecherlist=[]
sizelist=[]
datelist=[]
splitarr=[]
magnetlinks=[]
#split scraping process into three threads
def task1(): 
    for url1 in splitarr[0]:
        scrape_induvidual(url1)
def task2():
    for url2 in splitarr[1]:
        scrape_induvidual(url2)
def task3():
    for url3 in splitarr[2]:
        scrape_induvidual(url3)

#function for scraping induvidual urls in urllist
def scrape_induvidual(url):
    source = scraper.get(url).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

    leftside=[]
    rightside=[]

    for h1_tag in soup.find('h1'):
        filenamelist.append(h1_tag)

    for ul_tag in soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'list'}):
        for li_tag in ul_tag.find_all('li'):
            for strong_tag in li_tag.find_all('strong'):
                leftside.append(strong_tag.text)
            for span_tag in li_tag.find_all('span'):
                rightside.append(span_tag.text)

    combined=(np.column_stack([leftside,rightside]))

    for each_detail in combined:
        if 'Seeders' in each_detail[0]:
            seederlist.append(each_detail[1])
        if 'Leechers' in each_detail[0]:
            leecherlist.append(each_detail[1])
        if 'Total size' in each_detail[0]:
            sizelist.append(each_detail[1])
        if 'Date uploaded' in each_detail[0]:
            datelist.append(each_detail[1])
    #get magnet link by looking for Magnet Download text and getting its parent anchor tag
    magnetlinks.append(soup.find(string="Magnet Download").find_parent('a').get('href'))

#extract page links for every torrent and store it in an array
for tag in tablebody.find_all('a'):
    temp_url=tag.get('href').split('/')
    if "torrent" in temp_url[1]:
      urllist.append('https://1337x.to'+(tag.get('href')))

#split array for parralel scraping
splitarr=np.array_split(urllist, 3)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t1') 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=task2, name='t2')   
t3 = threading.Thread(target=task3, name='t3')

t1.start() 
t2.start()
t3.start() 

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()

combined=(np.column_stack([filenamelist,seederlist,leecherlist,sizelist,datelist,magnetlinks]))
df = pd.DataFrame(combined)
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: If the script works then it's OK. Threading is  perfectly normal in this case. Another approach is using `asyncio`, but that would be overkill here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need or want threads for this, you can use [aiocfscrape](https://pypi.org/project/aiocfscrape/) instead of regular cfscrape, and then use asyncio to process requests concurrently in a single thread.

Having more threads in Python doesn't really improve your performance for this kind of use case, though on the other hand you already have the code written and it seems to be working so that's fine too.  Just don't think that you're getting a benefit from multiple threads per se--the benefit you're getting is being able to issue multiple requests at the same time, hiding some latency by processing one while another is in flight.

Comment: So, does threads making multiple requests in my case increase speed? or is it just placebo?

Comment: Yes, making multiple requests increases speed.  Imagine you want to play 100 games of chess by mail against a single opponent.  If you formulate your first move for all 100 games and send them out, then reply whenever you get a response, you will finish all 100 games much faster overall than if you sent just one move at a time and waited for the response.